# Making a read-only Linux SD card, where are the security loopholes? (offline key generation and signing)

Tags: linux, paper-wallet, offline

I have already identified a way to make an [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital) truly read-only [on HackaDay](http://hackaday.com/2013/11/12/keep-your-sd-cards-data-safe-with-the-sd-locker/).

So let's consider this situation:

- A third party have used [dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) to transfer the Linux image to an SD card
- The [PERM_WRITE_PROTECT](http://hackaday.com/2013/11/12/keep-your-sd-cards-data-safe-with-the-sd-locker/) bit is set and can not be changed
- There is a hash of the image that will be checked on booting from the card
- The developer have signed the hash with PGP and this is clearly stated online

The purpose of this card is to be able to boot a computer you already own and to know that what was intended to boot is actually running. Could [uEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) or BIOS in a computer be compromised?

Security should enable the user to:

- Generate a paper wallet
- Print the wallet with a USB connected printer
- (Other actions needing high security precautions)

To do this with confidence, both the SD card and [the code](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9112/how-can-i-verify-the-the-pgp-signature-of-bitaddress-org) to generate the keys must be verified (hash and PGP signatures) by the user. What am I missing? Are there any loopholes in this combination of hardware and software?

Comment: To answer this question, you have to clearly articulate which elements you do and don't trust.  The Linux developers could have included a back door.  The BIOS could be malicious.  The printer could log all the pages it prints.  The USB cable could have a sniffer that logs all the bits going through it.  Et cetera.  Which of these possibilities concern you?

Comment: @nate-eldredge BIOS/UEFI would be my first concern, a "dumb" printer could be used (with no storage possibility). The last physical vulnerability that I take in to account is when the SD-card was written to by the third party. So sniffer USB cable is not included in my question. Niter is a hardware keylogger or any [Tempest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_(codename)) conserns included.

Comment: I have removed the three tags that you created for this question and added [tag:paper-wallet]. Please only add tags that are on-topic and will be useful in a broader scope on this SE.